# Error "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" when using f2py in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, fortran, f2py

Following the [numpy github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11253), I have fixed the bug of `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` for **f2py**. However, when I continued to call the f2py function, an error appears.

```
## CODE
import numpy.f2py
source = '''
     subroutine foo
     print*, "Hello world!"
     end 
    '''  
numpy.f2py.compile(source, modulename='hello')
```

The error shows like this:

```
error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -L/usr/local/NETCDF/lib /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/hellomodule.o /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/fortranobject.o /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp95jyzlt5.o -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin8/4.2.3 -L/Users/HYF/anaconda/envs/py35/lib -lgfortran -o ./hello.cpython-35m-darwin.so" failed with exit status 1
ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/HYF/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/libgfortran.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/HYF/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/libgfortran.dylibignoring file /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/hellomodule.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xCF 0xFA 0xED 0xFE 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/hellomodule.oignoring file /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/fortranobject.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xCF 0xFA 0xED 0xFE 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/fortranobject.o


Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MAIN__", referenced from:
      _main in libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o)
  "__gfortran_set_args", referenced from:
      _main in libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o)
  "__gfortran_st_write", referenced from:
      _foo_ in tmp95jyzlt5.o
  "__gfortran_st_write_done", referenced from:
      _foo_ in tmp95jyzlt5.o
  "__gfortran_transfer_character", referenced from:
      _foo_ in tmp95jyzlt5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/HYF/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/libgfortran.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/HYF/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/libgfortran.dylibignoring file /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/hellomodule.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xCF 0xFA 0xED 0xFE 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/hellomodule.oignoring file /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/fortranobject.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xCF 0xFA 0xED 0xFE 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/var/folders/wg/d26_jxbj2p9gp7nkl90q0fbm0000gn/T/tmp52sjoxqw/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.5/fortranobject.o


Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MAIN__", referenced from:
      _main in libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o)
  "__gfortran_set_args", referenced from:
      _main in libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o)
  "__gfortran_st_write", referenced from:
      _foo_ in tmp95jyzlt5.o
  "__gfortran_st_write_done", referenced from:
      _foo_ in tmp95jyzlt5.o
  "__gfortran_transfer_character", referenced from:
      _foo_ in tmp95jyzlt5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The environment: Mac OSX 10.10.3, gcc 4.9.4, Python 3.5, numpy 1.14.5

I don't know how to fix this error, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It says the file the linker is using, e.g. libgfortran.dylib, is built for a different architecture. So, you may need a different version installed for your machine. But I'm guessing. It also doesn't like the hello program - but I'm not sure why.